# I need to include a javascript in a wordpress blog which has no plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need to include some JavaScript for a BMI calculator in a WordPress blog.

The BMI Calculator is [here](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/bmi-calculator/bmi-calculator.html).

However, WordPress strips out the code when the page is published.

Short of using some form of `iframe` to show the script, is there any other way?

Thanks, Christine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried embedding that particular script you mention in a page but every time I need to include any other javascript in my wordpress site I use the plugin:

http://www.matteoionescu.com/wordpress/embed-html/

This allows you to take advantage of the custom fields to insert code directly into the page.

Comment: Thanks Ryan that looks like what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted a jQuery script to an existing site before using javascript. Here is the code I used, you may be able to adapt it to add you library.

```
<script>
//Insert JQuery Javascript Library
if(!window.MyLibrary){window.MyLibrary={};s=document.createElement('script');s.type= 'text/javascript';s.src=window.location.href.replace(/((custompages)|(eware.dll)).*/i,'')+'custompages/jquery-1.4.4.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}
</script>
```

You may need to reference a library hosted on the internet rather than on wordpress